# Can I set a BuildConfig flag that returns whether or not an apk is built with the `connectedAndroidTest` gradle task?

Tags: android, gradle, android-testing, buildconfig

I have parts of my app that I don't want to run if we're running Android unit tests, so I want to surround them with something like

```
if (!BuildConfig.TESTING) {
  // Code here that I don't want to run during tests.
}
```

Is it possible to populate this `BuildConfig` flag depending on whether the `connectedAndroidTest` gradle task is used? Is this a sane way of approaching this problem?

Comment: AFAIK, what you want is not directly possible, as `BuildConfig` contents are determined by build type. Why aren't you just basing your decision on the build type?

Comment: Build type such as `DEBUG` vs `RELEASE`? There is some code like things that report to our analytics server that we want running in both DEBUG and RELEASE mode, but not when running through tests.

Comment: Then create a third build type for your unit tests. Or consider `debug` to be for the unit tests and create a third build type for whatever other role you are using for `debug` at present that requires analytics work.

Comment: Please [check this.](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html#change_the_test_build_type) It may be help you.

Comment: Another option I've used in the past is to create an `IsTest` class in the test source package, and then use reflection to check if the class `IsTest` exists.

Comment: Maybe you can create flavors and then just create two classes that are a bit different.

Answer (score -1):

This might be a little late, but oh well. Yes you can set `BuildConfig` fields through your app's gradle file, these will be initialized at build time. For example, I could save a debug flag through gradle like this:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "debuggable", "false"

    }

    debug {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "debuggable", "true"
    }
}
```

And the through code I could access the value like so:

```
if (!BuildConfig.debuggable) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Application is not Debuggable");
}
```